# What is the difference between homebrew casks 'dotnet' and 'dotnet-sdk' and formula 'dotnet'

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Running `brew search dotnet` shows the following

```
❯ brew search dotnet
==> Formulae
dotnet                                                                  dotbot

==> Casks
dotnet-preview                      dotnet-sdk-preview                  dotnet                              dotnet-sdk ✔
```

I am interested to know what are the differences between

- the cask `dotnet`
- the cask `dotnet-sdk`
- the formula `dotnet`

I am guessing the casks are the SDK and the runtime of dotnet (i.e. similar to what the JDK and the JRE are, you need `dotnet` to run a .NET app and `dotnet-sdk` to compile and develop one. But what is the forumla (non-cask) version of `dotnet` do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a good question. In general, the main difference between cask and core is cask is installing from the artifacts built by vendors, while core is built from the source code. (And core formulae has a `license` field thing to enforce the OSS nature of the software).

On top of that, `dotnet` helps to build other homebrew formulae. Right now, there are three formulae depend on `dotnet`:

- `archi-steam-farm`
- `dafny`
- `gitversion`